# Changing Background of a div from a dynamicclass

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic

I have some jQuery that *dynamically* generates classes for a list of links and gets the links from a XML Sheet as follows: -

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="link1fromxml" class="background1"></a></li>
    <li><a href="link2fromxml" class="background2"></a></li>
    <li><a href="link3fromxml" class="background3"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Now what I need to do is from the links with generated classes when clicked, change the background of another `div` and get the source from my XML file. This is my code for this.

```
$(xml).find("large").each(function(i) {
    var url = $(this).find('urllarge').text();
    $('.background' + i).live('click', function() {
        $('bigImage').css('background-image', 'url(' + urllarge + ')');
    });
});
```

However it's being a pain and not working and I can't see where I'm going wrong any help given will be greatly appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "images.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml
  });
});

function parseXml(xml)

$(xml).find("large").each(function(i) {

    $('.background' + i).live('click', function() {
        $('bigImage').css('background-image', 'url(' + urllarge + ')');
    });

});

});
```

XML is: -

```
<image>
<large>
<urllarge>img/bigimage.jpg</urllarge>
</large>
</image>
```

Comment: Can you please post both how you are retrieving `xml` and its value.

Comment: Where does the variable urllarge in the parseXml function come from? Shouldn't it be just url? Like this: $('bigImage').css('background-image', 'url(' + url + ')');

Comment: Added to original question.

Comment: Updated my original code, your right griffla, Don't need that variable.

Comment: Use of the `.live()` method is no longer recommended since later versions of jQuery offer better methods that do not have its drawbacks. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Roy,switched .live for .on now.

Answer (score 1):

Your parse xml function is missing {}   It should be like:

```
function parseXml(xml) {

  $(xml).find("large").each(function(i) {

    $('.background' + i).live('click', function() {
      $('bigImage').css('background-image', 'url(' + urllarge + ')');
    });

  });
}
```